# NHibernate - Query with value object containing NULL values

Tags: nhibernate

I have a value object like this:

```
public class PersonMapping : ComponentMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMapping()
    {
        Map(x => x.FirstName).Not.Nullable().Length(96);
        Map(x => x.LastName).Not.Nullable().Length(96);
        Map(x => x.MiddleName).Nullable().Length(96);
        Map(x => x.NickName).Nullable().Length(64);
    }
}
```

I create a query like so:

```
var owner = new Person("Anneliese", "ObjectOfficer_1");
var query = NhSession.Query<ServiceContract>()
                .Where(s => s.ObjectOfficer.Manager == owner);
contracts = query.ToList();
```

This creates an instance of `Person` that has a `null` MiddleName and Nickname. NHibernate creates a query like so:

```
select .....
from .....
where (objectoffi1_.FirstName = @p0 
      and objectoffi1_.LastName = @p1 
      and objectoffi1_.MiddleName = @p2 
      and objectoffi1_.NickName = @p3);
  @p0 = 'Anneliese' [Type: String (4000)], 
  @p1 = 'ObjectOfficer_1' [Type: String (4000)], 
  @p2 = NULL [Type: String (4000)], 
  @p3 = NULL [Type: String (4000)]
```

**No records match which is wrong.**

When I change the generated query and replace the parameters with values like so:

```
...
where (objectoffi1_.FirstName = 'Anneliese' and objectoffi1_.LastName = 'ObjectOfficer_1' 
and objectoffi1_.NickName is null and objectoffi1_.MiddleName is null)
```

it returns a correct number of results. Does anybody know how to deal with this? If NHibernate sends **field = NULL** instead **field is null** to MS SQL Server, no results are returned since it is **wrong TSQL**. Any ideas?

Comment: what nhibernate version are you using and what mssqldialect?

Comment: Newest versions, NH 4.0.4.4000, FNH 2.0.3, SQL Dialect 2012, SQL Server 2014 is what I use but 2012 is the latest supported by NH.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that it is not possible to put value objects with nullable properties in a where clause. You have to care about these potential null values yourself in your code. Once you compare the fields directly field by field it works. Here the 'correct' version:

```
var query = NhSession.Query<ServiceContract>()
                .Where(s => s.ObjectOfficer.Manager.FirstName == owner.FirstName 
                            && s.ObjectOfficer.Manager.LastName == owner.LastName);
contracts = query.ToList();
```

I think this is more than just inconvenient and I do not know if other ORMs such as EF have the same problem. Value Objects are an important building block of DDD.